# How do I configure Spark's "per bucket" settings for complex S3 bucket names?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark

For "per bucket" settings, if I have an S3 bucket name `my.whole.name` with dots (periods) in the name, how do I escape or include them in the Spark settings? Quotes do not work:

`sparkConf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a."my.whole.name".access.key',<redacted>)`

Reference on "per bucket" access configuration, but does not mention complex bucket names:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configuring_different_S3_buckets_with_Per-Bucket_Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting "bucket" in the configuration and removing the quotes:

```
 sparkConf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.my.whole.name.access.key',<redacted>)
```

It should be parsed internally by Spark.

Comment: Despite the downvote, this method to address a bucket with dots in its name is working for me as of Spark 3.2.2 and Hadoop 3.2.2 to add per bucket options. Per bucket instructions here: https://github.com/choyrim/sparkhacks-hadoop291#usage-per-bucket also describe the usage of per bucket options for a bucket with dots in its name.

Answer (score -1):

s3a doesn't support per bucket settings with dots in their name. no way to work out what is the bucket and what is the option. AWS docs say such names "not recommended for uses other than static website hosting"

see [SPARK-32766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32766) for more on this.

Comment: Dots in the name are working for me as of Spark 3.2.2 and Hadoop 3.2.2 to add per bucket options. Following your link, someone linked to AWS extending the deprecation as of 2020: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/ .

Comment: really? not a supported feature in the s3a code at all. certainly all bug reports will be closed as WONTFIX.